# Memory exhausted even when there is a lot of memory allocated

Tags: php, wordpress

I realize that there are a lot of similar threads and I checked all of them. I've tried to increase the memory limit in `php.ini`, `wp-config.php`, `wp-settings.php` but nothing help.

Current error is:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2516

My limits in php.ini are

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 8192M
post_max_size = 256M
```

I don't know what to increase anymore.

edit: `phpinfo()` shows this

[image]

Edit: `wp-db.php`

Error is here:

```
 else {
            // ...column name-keyed row arrays
            $new_array[] = get_object_vars( $row );
 }
```

and this is the full function (sorry for the long code)

```
    /**
 * Retrieve an entire SQL result set from the database (i.e., many rows)
 *
 * Executes a SQL query and returns the entire SQL result.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $query  SQL query.
 * @param string $output Optional. Any of ARRAY_A | ARRAY_N | OBJECT | OBJECT_K constants.
 *                       With one of the first three, return an array of rows indexed from 0 by SQL result row number.
 *                       Each row is an associative array (column => value, ...), a numerically indexed array (0 => value, ...), or an object. ( ->column = value ), respectively.
 *                       With OBJECT_K, return an associative array of row objects keyed by the value of each row's first column's value.
 *                       Duplicate keys are discarded.
 * @return array|object|null Database query results
 */
public function get_results( $query = null, $output = OBJECT ) {
    $this->func_call = "\$db->get_results(\"$query\", $output)";

    if ( $this->check_current_query && $this->check_safe_collation( $query ) ) {
        $this->check_current_query = false;
    }

    if ( $query ) {
        $this->query( $query );
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    $new_array = array();
    if ( $output == OBJECT ) {
        // Return an integer-keyed array of row objects
        return $this->last_result;
    } elseif ( $output == OBJECT_K ) {
        // Return an array of row objects with keys from column 1
        // (Duplicates are discarded)
        foreach ( $this->last_result as $row ) {
            $var_by_ref = get_object_vars( $row );
            $key = array_shift( $var_by_ref );
            if ( ! isset( $new_array[ $key ] ) )
                $new_array[ $key ] = $row;
        }
        return $new_array;
    } elseif ( $output == ARRAY_A || $output == ARRAY_N ) {
        // Return an integer-keyed array of...
        if ( $this->last_result ) {
            foreach ( (array) $this->last_result as $row ) {
                if ( $output == ARRAY_N ) {
                    // ...integer-keyed row arrays
                    $new_array[] = array_values( get_object_vars( $row ) );
                } else {
                    // ...column name-keyed row arrays
                    $new_array[] = get_object_vars( $row );
                }
            }
        }
        return $new_array;
    } elseif ( strtoupper( $output ) === OBJECT ) {
        // Back compat for OBJECT being previously case insensitive.
        return $this->last_result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Check your db queries. Make sure they're efficiently using your resources.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. It is WPML plugin which caused this error. When I started it and tried to gather all strings for translate or something like this. I can't switched it off also because I don't have access to the admin part

Comment: Can you please create a php file that shows your phpinfo and make sure that php has access to the memory you are setting.http://php.net/manual/ro/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: To disable a plugin you can use your ftp and rename the plugin folder, it will diable it.

Comment: I have added image of my phpinfo() result

Comment: Can you paste the line 256 of /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php?

Comment: I've added the problem part in `wp-db.php` and whole function aswell.

Comment: Is this on a shared hosting provider? They might have the memory limit capped somewhere that you can't control.

Comment: Yes, it is shared hosting. But if is some limit from the hosting I assume I should see less resources limit in `phpinfo()` or not necessarily?

Comment: You may wanna try adding - `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );` and `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );` - in your wp-config.php that is located at the base of your site. See if that'll work.

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't change it. I've also renamed the plugins which are connected with `WPML` and found the problem part - addition plugin which is `WPML String Translation`.